# Virtual linux system

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtual

I want to install a virtual linux system within my Windows7 operating system. I was thinking of using Cygwin. Any suggestions of other good/better softwares to use?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

For running UNIX-y apps within Windows, Cygwin is pretty much the de-facto standard. The programs that are installable through Cygwin are essentially clones of the Linux ones, but compiled under Windows so that they run natively. Note though that you can't run a Linux program under Cygwin.

On the other hand if you want to run native Linux programs or a Linux distribution like Ubuntu, you'll need something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help but mention the amazing JavaScript PC emulator running Linux .. http://bellard.org/jslinux/ since you do not specify what you are trying to do with Linux, that may well answer your needs.